# How to multiple rows are melted in R?

Tags: r, reshape, melt

I have a data set.

```
structure(list(X = c("ID", NA, "TOM", "TOM", "TOM", "TOM", "TOM", 
"JAY", "JAY", "JAY", "JAY", "JAY"), X.1 = c("number", NA, "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2"), X.4 = c("10/1", 
"1", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.5 = c("10/1", 
"2", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.6 = c("10/1", 
"3", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.7 = c("10/1", 
"4", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.8 = c("10/1", 
"5", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.9 = c("10/1", 
"6", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.10 = c("10/1", 
"7", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.11 = c("10/1", 
"8", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.13 = c("10/2", 
"1", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.14 = c("10/2", 
"2", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.15 = c("10/2", 
"3", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.16 = c("10/2", 
"4", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.17 = c("10/2", 
"5", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.18 = c("10/2", 
"6", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.19 = c("10/2", 
"7", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X.20 = c("10/2", 
"8", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a")), row.names = c(3L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L), class = "data.frame")


ID number 10/1 10/1 10/1 10/2 10/2 10/2
N/A N/A    1    2    3    1     2    3
Tom  1     a    a    a    a     a    a
Jay  1     a    a    a    a     a    a
```

I want to melt date like 10/1... and division like 1, 2, 3 into columns.

What I want is:

```
ID number variable1 variable2 value
Tom  1       10/1       1       a
Tom  1       10/1       2       a
Tom  1       10/1       3       a
Tom  1       10/2       1       a
Tom  1       10/2       2       a
Tom  1       10/2       3       a
Jay  1       10/1       1       a
Jay  1       10/1       2       a
Jay  1       10/1       3       a
Jay  1       10/2       1       a
Jay  1       10/2       2       a
Jay  1       10/2       3       a
Jay  1       10/1       1       a
```

The melt function of reshape2 supports only one pair of column names.

Comment: Please make your input data reproducible (Check out `dput()` if you haven't)

Comment: Does that answer your quesiton? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format

Comment: @deschen No.. I want to transform date (10/1, 10/2...) and 1, 2, 3 row data.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate. The linked answer doesn't answer this question because this example has a second ID row in the data frame

Comment: If your data are `df` then reset the names using
`df_names <- paste(names(df), df[1,], sep = "_") `
 then: `names(df)[3:8] <- df_names[3:8]`,
then use `pivot_longer ` from `tidyr` or `tidyverse` : 
`df[2:nrow(df),] %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = !c(ID, number),
    names_to = c("variable1", "variable2"),
    names_sep = "_",
    values_to = "value"
  )`

Comment: I still consider this a duplicate. The only difference is to a) get rid of the first row and then after reshaping to long format, append the 1, 2, 3 info through a simple `rep(1:3, 6)` thing.

Comment: @Scransom This seems to work fine. I'll give it a try.

Comment: "...this a duplicate. The only difference..." :thinking_face_emoji: